# How to make the content in a box (diagram) be centred?

Tags: diagrams

How to make the content in a box (diagram) be centred?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                chains,
                fit,
                positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 0mm,
  start chain = going below,
   arr/.style = {thick, -{Triangle[angle=60:3pt 2]}, semithick},
   box/.style = {draw, dashed, fill=white,
                 minimum height=#1, text width=64mm,
                 inner sep=2mm, font=\small\sffamily,},
 sound/.style = {box, solid,
                 text width=36mm,  
                %   text width=30mm,  
                 on chain, join=by arr},
                        ]
\node (f1) [box=24mm] {};
    \node (f1c) [sound, above=of f1.south]        {ABC};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I had tried:

```
   box/.style = {draw, dashed, fill=white,
                 minimum height=#1, text width=64mm,
                 inner sep=2mm, font=\small\sffamily,},
```

by adding `centre`, its not working

Comment: `\node (f1c) [sound, above=of f1.south, align=center]` (note: not centre) in the node works.

Comment: @Marijin. Thanks. it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like to have all `sound` boxes with centered node contents, than add `align=center` to `sound`'s style definition:

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                chains,
                fit,
                positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 0mm,
  start chain = going below,
   arr/.style = {thick, -{Triangle[angle=60:3pt 2]}, semithick},
   box/.style = {draw, dashed, fill=white,
                 minimum height=#1, text width=64mm,
                 inner sep=2mm, font=\small\sffamily,},
 sound/.style = {box, solid,
                 text width=36mm, 
                %   text width=30mm,
                 align=center,
                 on chain, join=by arr},
                        ]
\node (f1) [box=24mm] {};
    \node (f1c) [sound, above=of f1.south]        {ABC};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

in the case, when you like to center only one node contets, than add this option to node's options:

```
\node (f1) [box=24mm] {};
    \node (f1c) [sound, align=center,
                 above=of f1.south]        {ABC};
```